# How to sum values of matching columns while merging two dataframes in r

Tags: r

I have two dataframes in r

```
ship_no    bay_1   bay_2    bay_3    bay_5     bay_6
 ABC        0       10       15       20        30
 DEF        10      20       0        25        10
 ERT        0       10       0        10         0


ship_no    bay_1   bay_2    bay_7    bay_5     bay_6
 ABC        10      10       10       0         0
 DEF        10      10       0        15        10
 ERT        0       0        0        10        0
```

I want to add columns values while merging above two dataframes on column key `ship_no`

My desired dataframe would be

```
ship_no    bay_1   bay_2    bay_3    bay_5     bay_6     bay_7
  ABC        10      20       15       20        30       10
  DEF        20      30       0        40        20        0
  ERT        0       10       0        20        0         0
```

How can I do it in r?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can place the datasets in a `list`, use `rbindlist` to rbind the datasets, grouped by 'ship_no', get the `sum` of other columns

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(df1, df2), fill = TRUE)[,lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE) , ship_no]
#   ship_no bay_1 bay_2 bay_3 bay_5 bay_6 bay_7
#1:     ABC    10    20    15    20    30    10
#2:     DEF    20    30     0    40    20     0
#3:     ERT     0    10     0    20     0     0
```

---

Another option would be `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df1, df2) %>%
            group_by(ship_no) %>%
            summarise_all(funs(sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))
# A tibble: 3 x 7
#  ship_no bay_1 bay_2 bay_3 bay_5 bay_6 bay_7
#    <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     ABC    10    20    15    20    30    10
#2     DEF    20    30     0    40    20     0
#3     ERT     0    10     0    20     0     0
```